# error C2664: 'func' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'const int *&' Conversion loses qualifiers

Tags: c++

My code listed as follow:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printa(const int * & p)
{
    //*p = 20;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;

    int * p = &a;

    printa(p);

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But I got error message:

```
error C2664: 'func' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'const int *&'  
> Conversion loses qualifiers
```

when call "printa(p)" statesment.

I fixed it by type:

```
printa((const int *&)p);
```

But, I don't know why.

And I think the function of "printa()" not modify the value of parameter. So, I want declare the function using const like that.

Who can tell me what reason make this happen?

By the way, I'm using VS2010.

Comment: Why pass-by-reference? Why not just `void printa(const int * p)`?

Comment: Oh, that's a good question. Because I'm a newer to C++. I tried that way to fix this, and it's works undoubtedly. But as I said, I'm newer. So I want to know how C++ compiler worked.